# How to scroll up and down in a terminal with PgUp and PgDn keys?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal, lxterminal

In gnome-terminal, lxterminal and mlterm under Lubuntu 16.04, when pressing PgUp nothing happens, and the symbol `~` appears when PgDn is pressed, but the information won't scroll up or down. This is not the case for navigators and text editors, where they behave as expected. How can this be changed for a terminal?

Comment: Try shift+PageUp

Comment: @DevilaN That solved the problem. Not that I can't get used to it, but need the same behavior in the editor and terminal. Is there any way to change this association?

Comment: These shortcuts cannot be changed in gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem that has to be solved for each particular terminal. In the case of `mlterm` you add these lines to the shortcuts file `~/.mlterm/key`:

```
Prior=PAGE_UP
Next=PAGE_DOWN
```

As for gnome-terminal and lxterminal, the preferences window does not allow to change this.

Answer (score 1):

I use `Shift+pgUP` and `Shift+pgDOWN`. this key combination provides page scrolling.

I am using Ubuntu though.

Comment: But, where is this keybinding established and how to change it for a terminal?